# React Native options presentation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

React Native options presentation not working no errors but the pop on click is normal not modal
<HomeStack.Screen  name="TweetDetailsScreen" component={TweetDetailsScreen}
options={{presentation:"transparentModal"}} this is the part where i am using presentation i dont know why it is not working

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import Feed from './screens/tabScreens/Feed'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Settings from './screens/tabScreens/Settings';
import Notifications from './screens/tabScreens/Notifications';
import { Ionicons, Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import TweetDetailsScreen from './screens/homeStack/TweetDetailsScreen';


const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackGroup(){
    return(
        <HomeStack.Navigator>
            <HomeStack.Screen  name="Feed" component={Feed}/>
            <HomeStack.Screen  name="TweetDetailsScreen" component={TweetDetailsScreen}
            options={{presentation:"transparentModal"}}
            /> 

        </HomeStack.Navigator>
    );
}
 
const Tab= createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabGroup(){
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({route, Navigation}) =>({
            tabBarIcon:({color,focused,size}) =>{
                let iconName;
                if(route.name==='HomeStackGroup'){
                    iconName = focused ? "home" : "home-outline";
                }else if (route.name === "Settings") {
                    iconName = focused ? "settings-sharp" : "settings-outline";
                  } else if (route.name === "Notifications") {
                    iconName = focused ? "notifications-circle-sharp" : "notifications-circle-outline";
                  }

                return<Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>

            }
        })
    }

        >
            <Tab.Screen name="HomeStackGroup" component={HomeStackGroup} options={{headerShown :false , tabBarLabel:'@Aryan44'}}/>
         
            <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>


        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default function Navigator(){
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <TabGroup />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: `the pop on click is normal not modal` - edit your question to explain this part in more detail.

Comment: modal was not working ig its an android issue read somwhere else thanks